# Error with latest version Xamarin.Forms Button.CornerRadius

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

[Update: Code worked on Android 8.0 simulator]
I keep receive error No CornerRadius property found for the type Button
My code behind

```
public TabbedPage1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FindByName<Button>("runButton").CornerRadius = screenX / 5;
    }
```

My xaml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FuckThis.TabbedPage1">
    <ContentPage x:Name="Page1">
        <RelativeLayout>
            <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    x:Name="runButton"
                    Text="Run"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.4}"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.4}"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.3}"
                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.3}"
                    BorderRadius="200"
                    CornerRadius="200"
             />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

I've tried BorderRadius but it didnt work due to new Xamarin.Forms version 3.1
In another try, CornerRadius worked on Android and showed error on iOS, but then I tried to create new project and all f...ed up, now it's bug on Android also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public TabbedPage1 ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    runButton.CornerRadius = screenX / 5;
}
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit?

Comment: but nvm, i found a way to fix it :v